# Testing DNS set on VM(Ubuntu server) on Windows host PC

Tags: dns

I am new to this community. I am currently studying computer science and I am trying to practice some stuff here at home while locked. So at the university we have computers that are connected to the server with network connection. We have a task to configure another network card in that computer that we will use to connect clients to it. We have to configure NAT, DNS and DHCP on that card and after it connect it to 3rd laptop to test everyhing.

I am unable to test this at home with this setup since I only have my computer and virtualbox. My question is:

Is there a way I could test DNS I set on virtualbox (Ubuntu server) and on virtual "net card" on my host PC on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For relatively simple networks, you can create internal networks, to which you can connect the network adapters of virtualbox machines.

You should however make a drawing of your required network first. For each separate network segment, you create a `vboxnetx`. Creating such an network segment is under "file"->"host network manager" (at least: in my version of virtual box)

You can create a network like this:

```
+-----------+      +-----------+
|dns server |      | dns client|
+-----------+      +-----------+
      |                  |
  -----------------------------------vboxnet0
```

For configuring NAT, you will need a vm with two network interfaces:

- one connected to vboxnet0 (hostonly adapter)
- one bridged to the outside interface of your host

making the picture:

```
 +----------+    +----------+  +----------+
 |dns server|    |dns client|  |nat system|-----------bridged adapter
 +----------+    +----------+  +----------+
      |               |              |
    ----------------------------------------------- vboxnet0
```

If  you need more complex networks, there are routers that can be used as virtualbox VM. I have even had a Palo Alto firewall as a VM.

When your network requirements grow beyond that, you may want to check-out `gns3`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effor. I managed to do it all by myself. It works and Im ready for the exam tomorrow! Thanks man , I really appreciate it.